# Why try except not works in django filter?

Tags: django

Here is my filter class:

```
class PackageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
regex = django_filters.CharFilter(method="regex_filter")

class Meta:
    model = models.Package
    fields = {
        'package': ['exact'],
    }

def regex_filter(self, queryset, _, value):
    try:
        return queryset.filter(package__regex=value)
    except:
        raise ParseError('{} is invalid regex!'.format(value))
```

when i deliver python-2.\d+* to backend 
 backend should return `400 python-2\.\d+* is invalid regex!` 
 but actually not, it return

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in **exit**
89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: DataError at /api/v3/packages/
Exception Value: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Comment: Calling `.filter()` on a queryset does not cause it to be executed, you need to perform this validation yourself

Comment: Yes, make sense!